# Capacitors - a newbie's questions

Tags: capacitor

I know how capacitors work, and I know that 1 Farad is 1 coulomb at 1 volt,
but I'm not completely sure how they fit in with the rest of electronics. I looked at circuit diagrams, but why does there need to be a resistor?
I'm missing some small piece of the whole thing that ties everything together.
Any explanations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: "why does there need to be a resistor" - a resistor in what?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Can you be more specific? Please also read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Firstly, your understanding of the phrase 'rest of electronics' might be clear to you, but it is a very broader perspective. Try to be more specific, to get (better) answers. Second, I think you are talking about a 'resistor' used in the capacitor circuits that you've found. That resistor is obviously not needed in every circuit with capacitor. To get a better idea of a capacitor in a circuit, try understanding any such circuit's behavior with a DC supply voltage and compare with that of AC supply voltage.

Comment: Your question seems to contain a false premise. There does not always need to be a resistor.

Answer (score 2):

When we draw a circuit diagram we often leave out (insignificant) details that would clutter up the circuit. These simplifications are well understood by engineers. However,this can produce misunderstanding by students who are not familiar with these simplifications as I think is demonstrated by this question.

Example:

[image]

Suppose we have a simple capacitor charge and discharge circuit (without a 'resistor' in the circuit).

At first sight we might **assume** there is no resistance in the circuit (or any other elements) and draw the circuit as shown. This would lead to a **wrong conclusion** that somehow we would get an infinite current when we closed the switch.

In reality even this simple circuit is more complicated.

*The second set of circuits highlights the wrong assumptions:*

(1) There is no resistance.

There is always resistance in the circuit (even if you made the wires of superconductors).

(2) There is no inductance or other passive elements in the circuit.

There is always inductance in a circuit which limits the rate of rise of current and creates a magnetic field (stores energy).

There is always parasitic capacitance between conductors.

In normal circumstance we can safely ignore these small resistances and inductances (and parasitic capacitances) because **they are not significant compared with other components** in the circuit or the frequencies used in that circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A capacitor of one farad contains 1 coulomb of separated charge if the voltage is 1 volt. Physically, this consists of two conductive plates separated by a dielectric. But now what? In order to do any work, the charges will need to equalize. This flow of charge is current. If the resistance between the two plates is infinite, no current flows. If the resistance is zero (as in a superconductor), just for an instant the current will be infinite. Neither situation is useful. Instead, to get a limited flow of current a resistor is inserted. At any instant the voltage, current and resistance are related by V=iR or, if you like, R=V/i. Like I say, without a finite resistance connecting a voltage, the current is either infinite or zero.

Comment: So how comes that every decoupling capacitor in the world is connected with no series resistance at all? IMHO your answer is not correct

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami - Well, the question was not at all clear, so I did the best I could to answer the question I think was intended. The point of decoupling caps is that that provide very high instantaneous current in order to maintain the supply voltage. Thus, no series resistors. In fact, decoupling caps are limited at high frequencies by parasitic resistance and inductance. Note the existence of higher-priced "low ESR" caps.

Comment: Well you cannot cure the confusion created by a bad question with more confusion from a bad answer. You are an experienced user, you should know better. If I were you, I would erase that answer... "Infinite current"... Come on!

Comment: It is infinite current but only for an infinitely short time. So it is OK. The energy is still finite. In the limit as delta-t approaches zero.

Comment: An interesting question, though, is this: the capacitor had stored energy. Into what form was that energy transformed when the cap was discharged with zero resistance?

Comment: There is not such a thing as infinite current in the real world. I thought this was an engineering site with people that had a scope or a multimeter at least once in their hands. "Infinite current" is the typical nonsense of some poor teachers that never measured a current in their lives.

Comment: I am just having a little fun with you Claudio because you seem so serious. But all kidding aside, thinking about the overly ideal, impossible cases, can help you understand the more realistic cases. The energy stored in a capacitor is 0.5CV^2, right? Where does it go or what form is it converted to when you discharge the capacitor? This actually could help the OP understand why there must always be a resistance (but not necessarily a resistor as a separate discrete element). The alternative is the impossible (infinite current).

Comment: In that I agree with you. If you want to stick with ideal models, you have to understand that it is FORBIDDEN to shortcut an ideal capacitor, or to open a circuit with an ideal inductor in it. That could cause a big explosion, or a Big Bang.